# Чтение и редактирование PDF файла в PHP

Tags: pdf, php

Добрый день!
Посоветуйте либу, с помощью которой можно прочитать pdf файл, заменить плейсхолдеры и сохранить новый док. Либо прочитать pdf в html, там выполнить все операции и сгенерировать новый pdf.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот - [TCPDF is a FLOSS PHP class for generating PDF documents.](http://www.tcpdf.org/).

> Started in 2002, TCPDF is now one of the world's most active Open Source projects, used daily by millions of users and included in thousands of CMS and Web applications.

Comment: на сколько я понял TCPDF не позволяет редактировать существующий файл, только создание нового. Или может я ошибаюсь? Если можно пример плз